# Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't seem to use a array in a PDO statement here. It connects to the SQL Server properly, I just removed the user pass for security. When I run this script, it returns:

> Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare()

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've researched everywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

    $hello = "foo";

    try {
        $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=sql213.byethost16.com;dbname=b16_16742662_main", "b16_16742662", "00163827");
    } catch(Exception $e){
        die("ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM ajax_chat_registered_members WHERE NAME=:UserName AND PASS=:UserPass");
    $req->prepare(array('UserName'=>"Test",'UserPass'=>"foo"));

?>
```

Comment: Try `execute` instead of two `prepare`'s -> `$req->execute(array(...etc`

Comment: Thank you@Rasclatt and @Fred-ii- ! I'll try that. And I did see the manual part,but just needed clarification :-)

Comment: And a note on error handling, I already had that in.

Comment: That is a good practice to get into!

Comment: So is the question solved here by changing out the second `prepare()` with `execute()` ?

Comment: You need to take a more analytical approach to solving errors. The error message is literally telling you what is wrong, and which file/line the problem is in: you have a variable whose type is `PDOStatement`, and you are calling its `prepare()` method, but such a method does not exist on this class. The documentation lists the methods present in the `PDOStatement` class, and `prepare` is not one of them. In this case, like Rasclatt said, you want to use the `execute()` method instead.